# Remove shadow from beamer displaybox

Tags: beamer, shadows

I don't like shadows of the displaybox environment of beamer.

I've found this file `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemeumbcboxes.sty` which contains its declarations

```
\newenvironment{displaybox}[1]
{
  \centerline\bgroup\hfill
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[lower=umbcboxes,shadow=true,width=#1]{}
}
{
  \end{beamerboxesrounded}\hfill\egroup
}
```

I tried to change to `shadow=false` and then execute a `$texhash` but I keep getting shadows, can anyone tell me how to override this setting?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to change directly a system file; simply use a definition in your document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{displaybox}[1]
{
  \centerline\bgroup\hfill
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[lower=umbcboxes,shadow=false,width=#1]{}
}
{
  \end{beamerboxesrounded}\hfill\egroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{displaybox}{3cm}
test
\end{displaybox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you are loading a theme that already has the definition, simply change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` or use a different name for the environment.

Comment: that's exactly what I've just done! I didn't know how to define a new environment but then I guessed it from the syntax and it was easy. Thanks anyway!